# EXTJS add fireEvent to dynamically created elements using tpl

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an array of objects that I apply to html using `new Ext.XTemplate` and then I use the result as my html to a panel. When I click the button everything is fine using delegate.

**Question:**

How can I add events to the dynamically added buttons, so that I can use them in a controller?

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    var data = [{
        caption: 'Dashboard',
        myclass: 'dashboard'
    }, {
        caption: 'clients',
        myclass: 'clients'
    }];


    var myTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<table><tr>',
        '<tpl for="."><td>',
        '<div style="width:200px;background-color:#004544;" class="thumb-wrap">',
        '<button style="color:#fff;cursor:pointer;" class="{myclass}">{caption}</button>',
        '</div></td>',
        '</tpl></tr></table>');


    var htmlApplied = myTpl.apply(data);


    this.items = [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: htmlApplied,
        scope: me,
        listeners: {
            el: {
                delegate: 'button',
                click: function(clickcmp, button) {
                    console.log(clickcmp);
                    console.log(button);

                    switch (button.className) {
                        case 'dashboard':
                            this.fireEvent('menuload');


                            break;
                        case 'clients':
                            //alert('clients');
                            break;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }]

    this.addEvents({
        menuload: true
    });
}
```

> Controller

```
Ext.define("Something.Control", {

     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     refs: [],

     init: function() {
         this.control({
             'selector': {
                 menuload: this.activateMenu
             }
         });
     },

     activateMenu: function() {

     }

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `selector` matches the component code that you added above, what you're missing is the `scope` on the listener. By default, the scope will default to the inner panel. The `scope: me` needs to go down inside the el block:

```
el: {
    scope: this,
    delegate: 'div'
}
```